# Binding dynamic values to ng-model of a check-box with in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Inside my controller I have an array of objects like this:

```
this.set = [{
    "display": "Name",
    "pass": "name"
}, {
    "display": "Subject",
    "pass": "subject"
}, {
    "display": "Batch",
    "pass": "batch"
}];
```

I have provided checkboxes: `name, batch and subject`. Checking the checkboxes will filter a category.

**HTML:**

```
<div flex class="filters" layout="row"  ng-repeat="menu in menu">
    <md-checkbox  class="md-primary" ng-model="query.{{menu.pass}}">
        {{menu.display}}
    </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

`{{menu.display}}` Is displaying the names correctly. Now i want to dynamically bind the ng-model also. How is this possible?

Comment: don't you think `ng-repeat="menu in menu"` should be `ng-repeat="menu in menus"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ng-model attribute already expects an angular expression, so throwing in the curly braces inside that will not work, instead try something like:

```
<div flex class="filters" layout="row"  ng-repeat="menu in set">
    <md-checkbox  class="md-primary" ng-model="query[menu.pass]">
       {{menu.display}}
    </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

So now it's just setting `query.batch` by passing in the value of menu.pass.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/qvw9bmhe/32/

Just click on the names and see the query object update.